# Characteristic function of random variable is always integrable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $\phi$ be the characteristic function of $X$ . Is the integration of $|\phi|$ over $\mathbb R$ always finite?

I know how the characteristic function is defined. But how do I integrate it?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function of $X=0$ is $1$ at very point and this is not integrable.